# Set fire to people in chat

Tags: script, chrome-extensions, chat

How many times have you been overwhelmed by your desire to set fire to people in Stack Exchange chat? Well now you can!

## Arqade Fire

#### [Get Chrome Extension](http://tommedley.com/files/arqade-fire-1.0.2.crx)

#### [Get Grease Monkey User Script](http://tommedley.com/files/burn.user.js)

[image]

Arqade Fire is a chat message immolation tool that will burn away messages. It adds a small extra button next to flag, star and reply that will quickly incinerate the offending message.

It is a Chrome extension, simply download it and drag it into your Extensions page to install (you can drag directly from the download bar).

### Update 23/09/13

- Burns oneboxed images
- Removes a message group if all the messages within have been burned

Comment: You should change `@includes` to *chat.(etc) so https is supported.

Comment: Links are broken

Comment: Visit https://web.archive.org/http://tommedley.com/files/burn.user.js to install. I just tried and succeeded