# PONIES: Hide unwelcome images in chat

Tags: script, chat, images

Don't like it when chat is flooded with ponies? Too lazy to [burn them all](https://stackapps.com/q/4331/4644)? You need **PONIES: Protect Oneboxed Nuisance Images Everywhere Safely**.

[image]

All oneboxed images are displayed with 0.1 opacity until you mouse over them.

### [Get the Chrome Extension](http://tommedley.com/files/PONIES-1.0.crx)

Simply download it and drag it into your Extensions page to install (you can drag directly from the download bar).

If you wish to use the styles raw with Stylish, here they are:

```
img.user-image{
    opacity: 0.1;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
img.user-image:hover{
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out my userstyle version that does essentially the same (use with <s>stylish</s> stylus or adapt into a userscript):

```
/* SE chat − safe for work image oneboxes */

@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document domain("chat.stackexchange.com") {
  .ob-image, .ob-youtube {opacity: 0.1 !important;}
  .ob-image:hover, .ob-youtube:hover {opacity: 1 !important;}
}
```

Comment: This is a userstyle, not a userscript